# Want to change Payment method title in order detail page

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, payment-methods, payment, order-details

I want to change my new added payment method title in the order details page. There is a dynamic type which I get via my payment gateway.

It has to be like {my payment method title} /{that variable}. Which in my case would be like a {my payment Method} / wallet. I am getting the value of that variable in my controller file of my extension.

Comment: you need to change only in order detail page?

Comment: @SukumarGorai i want to append that dynamic variable to my Title via code

Comment: only for order view page?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya yes sir only at that page

Comment: @SukumarGorai yes ...

Comment: @SukumarGorai actually my payment method divide into further three steps like when user select my method he's redirected to an external page where he select sub-method after success it returns the variable  , so my payment method is actually divided into two parts. which i want to show in my order details page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto the below location:

> /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/tab/info.phtml

You will find the **Payment Information** there which is called on order details page. You can edit this according to your requirement and logic.

Also there are some more files where this information will shown like:

> app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/creditmemo/create/form.phtml
>
> app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/creditmemo/view/form.phtml
>
> app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/invoice/create/form.phtml
>
> app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/invoice/view/form.phtml
>
> app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/shipment/create/form.phtml
>
> app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/shipment/view/form.phtml

Hope this helps!

Comment: sir thanks a lot, but i gotta do this through the extension i've made for my added payment method. I can't make any change files the core files of magento

Comment: You can manage it through layout XML by setting up the template for that particular block

Comment: can we have a chat please ???

Comment: Sure give me 10 mins